# Found duplicate file for APK: LICENSE when deploying to my phone

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, guice

I am using Guice 2.0 for dependency injection in my android app. I included all its jars  in my libs folder.  The problem is that when I run it I am getting the following:

```
[2012-10-21 08:12:40 - PPSAndroid] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: LICENSE
Origin 1: C:\Users\zero-tolance\workspace\PPSAndroid\libs\guice-servlet-2.0.jar
Origin 2: C:\Users\zero-tolance\workspace\PPSAndroid\libs\guice-2.0.jar
```

I looked at other threads and they were very cryptic. I also did some searches and I couldn't find much about this.What I want to know is what is causing this problem  and how do I fix it.

Comment: Having same issue, ever solved?

Comment: What is guice-servlet-2.0.jar doing in an Android app?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the apk aggregates the resources from the libs, and both jars embed a `/LICENSE` file. Just remove it from `libs/guice-2.0.jar` and `libs/guice-servlet-2.0.jar`.